# How to deduplicate date sequences across non-consecutive rows in R?

Tags: r, tidyr, lubridate, date-manipulation, tibbletime

I want to flag the first date in every window of at least 31 days for each `id` in my data. 
Data:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(tibbletime)

D1 <- tibble(id = c(12,12,12,12,12,12,10,10,10,10),
             index_date=c("2019-01-01","2019-01-07","2019-01-21","2019-02-02",
                    "2019-02-09","2019-03-06","2019-01-05","2019-02-01","2019-02-02","2019-02-08"))
D1

# A tibble: 10 x 2
      id index_date
   <dbl> <chr>     
 1    12 2019-01-01
 2    12 2019-01-07
 3    12 2019-01-21
 4    12 2019-02-02
 5    12 2019-02-09
 6    12 2019-03-06
 7    10 2019-01-05
 8    10 2019-02-01
 9    10 2019-02-02
10    10 2019-02-08
```

The desired rows to flag are rows 1, 4, 6, 7, and 10; these rows represent either the first `index_date` for a given `id` or the first `index_date` after a 31-day skip period from the previously flagged `index_date` for that given `id`.

Code:

```
temp <- D1 %>%
  mutate(index_date = ymd(index_date)) %>%  
  arrange(id, index_date) %>%
  as_tbl_time(index_date) %>% 
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(keyed_to_index_date = 
           collapse_index(index_date, period = '31 d', side = "start"),
           keep = index_date == keyed_to_index_date)
temp %>% arrange(desc(id), index_date)
```

Result:

```
      id index_date keyed_to_index_date keep       
   <dbl> <date>     <date>              <lgl>
 1    12 2019-01-01 2019-01-01          TRUE 
 2    12 2019-01-07 2019-01-01          FALSE
 3    12 2019-01-21 2019-01-01          FALSE
 4    12 2019-02-02 2019-02-02          TRUE 
 5    12 2019-02-09 2019-02-02          FALSE
 6    12 2019-03-06 2019-03-06          TRUE 
 7    10 2019-01-05 2019-01-05          TRUE 
 8    10 2019-02-01 2019-02-01          TRUE 
 9    10 2019-02-02 2019-02-01          FALSE
10    10 2019-02-08 2019-02-01          FALSE
```

Why does this code flag row 8 (which has an `index_date` less than 31 days after the previously flagged `index_date` for that `id`) and not row 10, and how do I fix this problem?

UPDATE: 
 Adding the option `start_date = first(index_date)` to `collapse_index()`, as suggested by @mnaR99, successfully flagged the correct rows in the original example. However, when I applied the same principle to new data, I ran into a problem:

Data:

```
D2 <- tibble(id = c("A","A","A","B","B","B","B","B","C","C","C"),
             index_date = c("2019-03-04","2019-03-05","2019-03-06",
                            "2019-03-01","2019-03-02","2019-03-04","2019-03-05","2019-03-06",
                            "2019-03-03","2019-03-04","2019-03-05"))

D2
   id    index_date
   <chr> <chr>     
 1 A     2019-03-04
 2 A     2019-03-05
 3 A     2019-03-06
 4 B     2019-03-01
 5 B     2019-03-02
 6 B     2019-03-04
 7 B     2019-03-05
 8 B     2019-03-06
 9 C     2019-03-03
10 C     2019-03-04
11 C     2019-03-05
```

I now want to apply a 2-day window in the same manner as I previously applied a 31-day window (that is, consecutive calendar days should not both be flagged). The desired rows to flag are Rows 1, 3, 4, 6, 8, 9, and 11, because these rows are either the first `index_date` for a particular `id` or the first after a two-day skip. 
Code:

```
t3 <- D2 %>%
  mutate(index_date = ymd(index_date)) %>%  
  arrange(id, index_date) %>%
  as_tbl_time(index_date) %>% 
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(keyed_to_index_date = 
           collapse_index(index_date, 
                          period = '2 d', 
                          side = "start", 
                          start_date = first(index_date)),
         keep = index_date == keyed_to_index_date) %>%
  arrange(id, index_date)
```

Result:

```
> t3
# A time tibble: 11 x 4
# Index:  index_date
# Groups: id [3]
   id    index_date keyed_to_index_date keep 
   <chr> <date>     <date>              <lgl>
 1 A     2019-03-04 2019-03-04          TRUE 
 2 A     2019-03-05 2019-03-04          FALSE
 3 A     2019-03-06 2019-03-06          TRUE 
 4 B     2019-03-01 2019-03-01          TRUE 
 5 B     2019-03-02 2019-03-01          FALSE
 6 B     2019-03-04 2019-03-04          TRUE 
 7 B     2019-03-05 2019-03-05          TRUE 
 8 B     2019-03-06 2019-03-05          FALSE
 9 C     2019-03-03 2019-03-03          TRUE 
10 C     2019-03-04 2019-03-03          FALSE
11 C     2019-03-05 2019-03-05          TRUE
```

Row 7 is incorrectly flagged as TRUE, and Row 8 is incorrectly flagged as FALSE.

When I apply the `purrr` solution suggested by @tmfmnk,  I get the correct result. 
Code:

```
t4 <-
  D2 %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(index_date = ymd(index_date),
         keep =  row_number() == 1 | 
           accumulate(c(0, diff(index_date)), ~ if_else(.x >= 2, 
                                                        .y, 
                                                        .x + .y)
           ) >= 2
  )
```

Result:

```
> t4
# A tibble: 11 x 3
# Groups:   id [3]
   id    index_date keep 
   <chr> <date>     <lgl>
 1 A     2019-03-04 TRUE 
 2 A     2019-03-05 FALSE
 3 A     2019-03-06 TRUE 
 4 B     2019-03-01 TRUE 
 5 B     2019-03-02 FALSE
 6 B     2019-03-04 TRUE 
 7 B     2019-03-05 FALSE
 8 B     2019-03-06 TRUE 
 9 C     2019-03-03 TRUE 
10 C     2019-03-04 FALSE
11 C     2019-03-05 TRUE
```

What is wrong with the `tibbletime` approach in this example?

Comment: Incoporating the answers of @mnaR99 and trying to apply to new data

Answer (score 1):

One option utilizing `dplyr`, `lubridate` and `purrr` could be:

```
D1 %>%
 group_by(id) %>%
 mutate(index_date = ymd(index_date),
        keep =  row_number() == 1 | accumulate(c(0, diff(index_date)), ~ if_else(.x >= 31, .y, .x + .y)) >= 31)

     id index_date keep 
   <dbl> <date>     <lgl>
 1    12 2019-01-01 TRUE 
 2    12 2019-01-07 FALSE
 3    12 2019-01-21 FALSE
 4    12 2019-02-02 TRUE 
 5    12 2019-02-09 FALSE
 6    12 2019-03-06 TRUE 
 7    10 2019-01-05 TRUE 
 8    10 2019-02-01 FALSE
 9    10 2019-02-02 FALSE
10    10 2019-02-08 TRUE
```

Comment: This approach worked when I tried it on another example as well (see revised question), but the collapse_index() approach I had tried originally (and which was amended by @mnaR99) did not work when I tried it on a new example. Any idea why?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add the `start_date` argument to `collapse_index`:

```
D1 %>%
  mutate(index_date = ymd(index_date)) %>%  
  arrange(id, index_date) %>%
  as_tbl_time(index_date) %>% 
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(keyed_to_index_date = 
           collapse_index(index_date, period = '31 d', side = "start", start_date = first(index_date)),
           keep = index_date == keyed_to_index_date) %>% 
  arrange(desc(id), index_date)
#> # A time tibble: 10 x 4
#> # Index:  index_date
#> # Groups: id [2]
#>       id index_date keyed_to_index_date keep 
#>    <dbl> <date>     <date>              <lgl>
#>  1    12 2019-01-01 2019-01-01          TRUE 
#>  2    12 2019-01-07 2019-01-01          FALSE
#>  3    12 2019-01-21 2019-01-01          FALSE
#>  4    12 2019-02-02 2019-02-02          TRUE 
#>  5    12 2019-02-09 2019-02-02          FALSE
#>  6    12 2019-03-06 2019-03-06          TRUE 
#>  7    10 2019-01-05 2019-01-05          TRUE 
#>  8    10 2019-02-01 2019-01-05          FALSE
#>  9    10 2019-02-02 2019-01-05          FALSE
#> 10    10 2019-02-08 2019-02-08          TRUE
```

<sup>Created on 2020-09-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: This worked for my original example, but when I tried the same approach on a new example, I did not get the correct result; see updated question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `accumulate()` from `purrr`.

```
D1 %>%
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(index_date = ymd(index_date),
         keep = index_date == accumulate(index_date, ~ if(.y - .x >= 31) .y else .x))

#       id index_date keep 
#    <dbl> <date>     <lgl>
#  1    12 2019-01-01 TRUE 
#  2    12 2019-01-07 FALSE
#  3    12 2019-01-21 FALSE
#  4    12 2019-02-02 TRUE 
#  5    12 2019-02-09 FALSE
#  6    12 2019-03-06 TRUE 
#  7    10 2019-01-05 TRUE 
#  8    10 2019-02-01 FALSE
#  9    10 2019-02-02 FALSE
# 10    10 2019-02-08 TRUE
```

The iteration rule is following:

```
1. 2019-01-07 -  2019-01-01   = 6  <  31 then return  2019-01-01
2. 2019-01-21 -  2019-01-01   = 20 <  31 then return  2019-01-01
3. 2019-02-02 -  2019-01-01   = 32 >= 31 then return (2019-02-02)*
4. 2019-02-09 - (2019-02-02)* = 7  <  31 then return  2019-02-02
5. etc.
```